# Copy packages from old miktex to new miktex

Tags: miktex, updating

How to copy packages from old miktex 2.8 to new miktex 2.9.
I want installing  miktex2.9 but I can't  download all packages by slow internet,thus I want to copy this packages from installed miktex.
How to do this ?
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's probably a very, very, very bad idea to copy *old* packages into a (partially) updated installation. There might be severe inconsistencies. My advice: Handle with care, my stronger advice: don't do it at all!

Comment: I use the method described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/349031/script-to-setup-windows-for-already-installed-miktex/349097#349097) and it works well for me.

Answer (score 2):

Install only the basic version of MikTeX 2.9. Then it will install on the fly only the needed packages.

Comment: I install new basic miktex on old miktex without unistalling it ?

Comment: @QasemMarzei Yo should uninstall first the MikTeX 2.8 and later install cleanly the 2.9 version. As Herbert said install the basic MikTeX version, and install on the fly the packages as you need them. In this way you can work as before without wait centuries for the download.

Comment: @QasemMarzei: Delete the old installation and then install the new basic 2.9

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command line version of the package manager with the  `--import-all` switch. See http://docs.miktex.org/2.9/manual/mpm.html

Something like this:

```
mpm --repository=<path-to-miktex-2.8>  --import-all
```

If your miktex 2.8. was a multiuser installation it could be that your packages are in part in the USERINSTALL tree. I don't know if you can run `--import-all` on this tree too after you used it on the main tree.