# Can I save the list of installed Miktex (MPM) packages to a text file and install from that file in another installation?

Tags: miktex

I'd like to do similar as to what I can with Python - `pip freeze > installed.txt` and `pip install -r installed.txt`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Interesting question.

Comment: Good question. An alternative solution is to use the portable version of MikTeX (or TeXLive) instead. Then once you get it working, make a zip archive of the whole thing. Unzip it wherever desired. Also great for making a backup installation, in case your current installation is somehow disturbed.

Comment: Funny that you'd make that comment. I do use MikTeX portable however (through a fault of my own) I had managed to corrupt it but I was still able to interface with MPM, hence why I was trying to save the package list. Your suggestion is definitely a good one in general!

Answer (score 5):

In lieu of someone more in the know, I believe that I worked it out (although it turned out I didn't need it in the end).

I first used `mpm` to get a list of my installed packages (I used grep through Git Bash on my Windows machine).

```
mpm --list | grep ^i > installed.txt
```

However this contains more information than just names.

```
i 00003       1494 zerohyph
```

So I used Notepad++ to do a regex replace to find the stuff prior to the name and replace it with nothing.

```
^.*\d+
```

With a file which listed package names, I then ran the command to install the packages.

```
mpm --require=@installed.txt
```

Which seemed to work okay.

```
28 packages have been successfully installed.
```

I'm sure that this could be improved upon.

Comment: You could get rid of the Notepad++ step by using `awk` to grab the fourth column. This is included w/ Git Bash on Windows. 

`mpm --list | grep ^i | awk '{print $4}' > mpmlist.txt`.

Comment: Also, just in case, it might be worth running Git Bash as Administrator and using `mpm --admin --list` to start with.

Comment: Unfortunately --list is deprecated. https://docs.miktex.org/manual/mpm.html

Comment: This does not seem to handle the package version. It will only install the latest version of every package

Answer (score 2):

I use a different method when I upgrade Miktex as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/349031/script-to-setup-windows-for-already-installed-miktex/349097#349097). This can also be used to transfer an installation.